# Bluetooth disconnected on portrait/landscape change

Tags: android

I'm trying out the [BluetoothChat sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html), problem is, when you go between portrait/landscape mode, it disconnects. What would I need to do to maintain the connection and data through that change?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:

1. Move all the Bluetooth comm bits into a Service.
2. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29 to save the object that's holding the Bluetooth connection bits.
3. Use a global object (for example stashed into the Application object).